# Link to one of many divs with the same class?

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

Sometimes I want to send a link to e.g. an article in a newspaper and want the receiver to read a specific paragraph, chapter or similar. If the structure of the page is something like

```
<p class="h2">Some header
    <p class="body">Body text
```

etc. Is it possible to link to any of these element specifically? For example, I want someone to read the fourth paragraph, that is, the fourth time the class="h2" is used, something like . I know, but I don't recall the syntax ATM, that XPaths offers this functionality, but what about html?

Comment: Do you control the web pages you would like to link to? Because if not, then no, you can't. If you do, use [anchors in the markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2)

Comment: No, I don't control the webpage. If I did it would be easy using id or anchor tags. Hence my question.

Comment: Then you can't do it.

Comment: I guess I could send a RFE to Chrome or Firefox. It would be quite handy if you could link to either the 7th occurrence of a tag such as <p> or an id <p id="body"> that is used several times on page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome offers this functionality since a couple of months ago. Right-click on whatever you want to direct link to and select *Copy link to*. The result is something like this:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036942/link-to-one-of-many-divs-with-the-same-class#:~:text=If%20you%20visit-,following,-link%2C%20this%20will](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036942/link-to-one-of-many-divs-with-the-same-class#:%7E:text=If%20you%20visit-,following,-link%2C%20this%20will)

This is not supported on all browsers so far but I guess it, with time, will spread.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you http://www.web-source.net/html_link_anchors.htm#.Us-JX7T6SrE

```
<p class="h2"><a href="#text">Some header</a></p>
<p class="body" name="text">Body text</p>
```

Comment: The attribute "name" for elements other than input is deprecated. You may want to use attribute "id" instead.

Comment: I don't have control over the webpage. I want to link to specific elements (paragraphs) at, for example an article on a news site.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<p>
<a href="#C4">See also Chapter 4.</a>
</p>

<h2>Chapter 1</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 2</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 3</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2><a id="C4">Chapter 4</a></h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 5</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 6</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you visit following link, this will take you to bottom of the page  (this page explains the topic too):

http://www.myhtmltutorials.com/jump.html#Bot